# error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: did not find expected key

Tags: yaml

I keep getting error and this is my code below

```
apiVersion: "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
    kind: AzureIdentity
    metadata:
      name: {{.Values.managedIdentity.name }}
    spec:
      type: "0"
      resourceID: "{{ .Values.managedIdentity.resourceId }}"
      clientID: "{{ .Values.managedIdentity.clientId }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apiVersion` cannot have both the value `"aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"` and nested values (`kind`, `metadata` etc). You can *either* give a single value *or* nested values.